# Plotting gam model results in lattice

Tags: r, lattice, gam

I am fitting a model using `gam` from the `mgcv` package. I am storing the result in `model` and so far I have been looking at the smooth components using `plot(model)`. I have recently started using `lattice` and like its output. So I am wondering, is it possible to plot these graphs using `lattice`?

This my data set: https://gist.github.com/plxsas/fcef4a228c18c772b4f3

```
m2<- gam(TotalInd ~ s(dayinyear, by=as.numeric(Site=="1"), bs="cr")
  +s(dayinyear, by=as.numeric(Site=="2"), bs="cr") + s(dayinyear, 
   by=as.numeric(Site=="3"), bs="cr"), random=list(Replicate=~ 1), data=data)
```

How can I do plot this model in `lattice` package with three panels representing my three sites smoother,please?

You also might noticed that I have used the `dayinyear` instead of proper month format(the first column in the data). This is because Generalized additive models do not handle categorical variables. However, I would like to represent the time in my graph with the names of months (like in first column), Does any one know the way forward for that in a `lattice` plot?

Comment: Please edit your post, removing your data set and providing it on a separate link (using e.g. a gist on Github https://gist.github.com/) to improve readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general way to do it using some fake data. You will need to tweak this to make sure the names are as you like,

```
library(reshape)
library(mgcv)
library(lattice)

X1<-rnorm(100)   # Make some fake data
X2<-rnorm(100)
X3<-rnorm(100)
Y<-rnorm(100)

Mod<-gam(Y~s(X1,bs="cr")+s(X2,bs="cr")+s(X3, bs="cr")) # make a model

Z<- predict(Mod,type="terms", se.fit=T)  #Z is the predicted value 
                               #for each smooth term, se.fit give you SE

Z2<-melt(Z$fit)                     #Z was in wide form, Z2 is long form
Z2$XX<-c(X1,X2,X3)            #add the original values for he predictors 
Z2$SE<-melt(Z$se.fit)$value  #add SE
Z2$UP<-Z2$value+2*Z2$SE      #+2 SE
Z2$Low<-Z2$value-2*Z2$SE     # - 2 SE
Z2<-Z2[order(Z2$XX),]

xyplot(value~XX|X2,data=Z2,type="l",col="black",as.table=T,
     prepanel=function (x,y,...)list(ylim=c(min(Z2$Low),max(Z2$UP))),
     panel=function(x,y,groups,subscripts,...){
       panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
       panel.lines(Z2$UP[subscripts]~Z2$XX[subscripts],lty=2, col="red")
       panel.lines(Z2$Low[subscripts]~Z2$XX[subscripts],lty=2, col="red")
     }
 )
```

`value` is the predicted value for each predictor and `X2`is where the grouping variable is (indicates which data belongs to each predictor). If you are working we these a lot you should rename things to be clearer. The `order` part just avoids spaghetti plots

You can control the way the x-axis is labeled using the `at` and `labels` arguments for the x-axis in the `scales` argument. For details see `?xyplot`

#### Update - Here is a version that works with this data

```
m2<- gam(TotalInd ~ s(dayinyear, by=as.numeric(Site=="1"), bs="cr")
     +s(dayinyear, by=as.numeric(Site=="2"), bs="cr") 
     + s(dayinyear, by=as.numeric(Site=="3"), bs="cr"), 
     random=list(Replicate=~ 1), data=Data)


Z<- predict(m2,type="terms",se.fit=T) #Z is the predicted value and SE
Z2<-melt(Z$fit)                     #Z was in wide form, Z2 is long form

Z2$dayinyear<-Data$dayinyear        #add the original values for he predictors 
Z2$SE<-melt(Z$se.fit)$value
Z2$UP<-Z2$value+2*Z2$SE
Z2$Low<-Z2$value-2*Z2$SE

Z2<-Z2[Z2$value!=0,] #gets rid of excess zeroes

Z2<-Z2[order(Z2$dayinyear),]



xyplot(value~dayinyear|X2,data=Z2,type="l",col="black",as.table=T,
     prepanel=function (x,y,...)list(ylim=c(min(Z2$Low),max(Z2$UP))),
     panel=function(x,y,groups,subscripts,...){
       panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
       panel.lines(Z2$UP[subscripts]~Z2$dayinyear[subscripts],lty=2, col="red")
       panel.lines(Z2$Low[subscripts]~Z2$dayinyear[subscripts],lty=2, col="red")
     }
)
```

Note that I changed the name of the starting `data.frame` from `data` to `Data`

**EDIT** - I have added the two dashed lines that show + /- 2 SE for each plot

Comment: Thanks for you help but can you please make your answer specific to my example and data. You will find link to my data and may be looking at it will clarify my point. In my example I am applying one smoother variable which is the time of data collection and I want to see the seasonal trend in my three site with considering the three replicates in each site as random effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and I am really getting there. The graph is very similar to what I am trying to achieve but not identical (https://www.dropbox.com/s/28bwecbaksg4do9/plotting.pdf). I am following case study I have found in Mixed Effect Models and Extension in Ecology in R (Zuur et al., 2009)[chapter 18]. My data is quite similar to the data example in that chapter. They have plotted the model as in the following picture. https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmp1uuxj46n8s8t/Chapter%2018.jpg

Comment: They have plotted the model with the following script https://www.dropbox.com/s/8u5ixw7fxfqfezx/chapter18.docx. Can you please help me to tweak the script to suite my data set, I found it quite difficult to do that and I will really appreciate that.

Comment: Which section and figure is it in that chapter? I can't get to drop-box just now but I am familiar with the book.

Comment: The section is 18.3 A Statistical Data Analysis Strategy for DIN and the figure is Fig. 18.7 Estimated long-term smoother for each area obtained by the model in Equation (18.4)

Comment: Dear John Paul, Thank you very much so far for helping me. Would you be able to help in answering my last question, please? I will really appreciate you help

Comment: @user48386 I have added the SE lines. I did not really follow Zuur et al's code as that was complex and for older R versions, but I think this does the same thing and makes the same figures.

Comment: @user48386 Did this solve the issue? You should either indicate what is not working or accept that answer so that folks who have a similar issue in the future can use this.

Comment: Thank you very much John for help me and I really appreciate the time you dedicate for that. Yes, it work beatifully

Comment: @user48386 Glad to hear it. If you look at the top of my answer on the left there is a number (currently 0) up and down arrows and an outline of a check mark. When someone answers your question it is a good idea to click on the check mark. It will turn green and your question will be recorded as answered. You and the person who answered will also gain rep from this. Thanks JP